# Avoid Duplicate Message to consume by Kafka Consumer in java

Tags: apache-kafka

How to avoid to process duplicate message by kafka consumer where producer and consumer deployed different nodes

try with set auto commit false and do the auto commit once the consumer processed the message then manually do the auto commit
but due to consumer crash it did not help me